# How to prove the divergence of $\sum n z^n$ when $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

The problem comes from the Exercise 19 of Stein's Complex Analysis. It is trivial when $z=1$, but I cannot come up with a solution for other cases that $|z|=1$.

My effort is to compute the $\sum^{N}_{n=1} n z^n$, and prove that for any $M \in \mathbb{C}$, there exits some $N$, s.t. $|\sum^{N}_{n=1} n z^n|>|M|$.

Note that when $z\neq 1$, we have
$$
|\sum^{N}_{n=1} n z^n| = \frac{|z-(1+N)z^{N+1}+Nz^{N+2}|}{|1-z|^2}
$$
But I could not make it out by Triangular inequality.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Your approach complicates the problem a lot. I think you should abandon it. Just recall for a series $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n$ to be convergent, the sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ must tend to $0$.

The latter is clearly not true in your example, implying divergence.

---

For the case that you absolutely want to make your approach work, you can do it like this:

$$|z-(1+N)z^{N+1}+Nz^{N+2}| \ge  |-Nz^{N+1}+ Nz^{N+2}|  -  | z -z^{N+1}|$$
by inverse triangle inequality. Then note this equals, as $|z^{N+1}|=1$,
  $$N|-1+ z|  -  | z -z^{N+1}|$$
Finally bound  $| z -z^{N+1}| \le 2$ for a  lower bound of $$ \ge N|-1+ z| -2.$$ As $|-1+z|$ is non-zero and independent of $N$ this is fine.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I indeed should have thought of the necessary condition of convergence earlier.